Set size of WPF dialog in Loaded causes flickering and displays the default size first
For some reasons I cannot use SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" in xaml directly.I try to use the Loaded event. But it seems that when my size setting function is called, the dialog is already displayed. So I will see a dialog in (possibly) default size first and then after SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent is done, the dialog refreshes again in another size. I did some search and found that Loaded is already in the earliest stage where I can measure the correct size. So what is the correct way to avoid the first dialog in wrong size?
I also tried directly to set the size before ShowDialog();, but that results in a wrong size, possibly because the size is before the dialog is rendered.
Here is my code sample:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent;
    }

    void SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double maxWidth = 0;

        foreach (UIElement child in RootStackPanel.Children)
        {
            // Measure each child
            child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

            // Get the desired width of the current child
            double childWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;

            // If the child has margins, add them too
            if (child is FrameworkElement fe)
            {
                childWidth += fe.Margin.Left + fe.Margin.Right;
                if (fe is Control control)
                {
                    childWidth += control.Padding.Left + control.Padding.Right;
                }
            }

            // Keep track of the maximum width found
            if (childWidth > maxWidth)
            {
                maxWidth = childWidth;
            }
        }

        // Get StackPanel's own margins
        double parentMarginLeft = RootStackPanel.Margin.Left;
        double parentMarginRight = RootStackPanel.Margin.Right;
        maxWidth += parentMarginLeft + parentMarginRight;

        // Set the dialog width to the calculated width
        Width = maxWidth;
    }
}

And here is the xaml sample:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid x:Name="RootStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="this is a test text." />
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>


Why using Loaded if you can call SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent directly after InitializeComponent()?

Either way this autosizing doesn't work.

You mentioned ShowDialog, please refer to [mcve].

@Sinatr Yes this autosizing doesn't work possibly due to the bullet area of checkbox... I think by mentioning set the size just before ShowDialog, I got the wrong result because of my other counting problems. I think this should work same as simply calling the SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent after InitializeComponent()

I find out that it is not a counting problem. It does make a difference by calling SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent directly after InitializeComponent() and by Loaded += SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent.
I have a nested ListBox using ObservableCollection. And its size cannot be calculated correctly directly after InitializeComponent(). Something is needed, maybe render

The "Loaded" event is for when the window is "ready for interaction"; which is hardly the case here. The key is in the XAML and "fluent" layout designs; which usually means "Stretch" and "Star" Grid Columns; and hardly ever "Center" for a parent control.

How about simply:
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RootStackPanel.Measure(new (double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    Width = RootStackPanel.DesiredSize.Width + RootStackPanel.Margin.Left + RootStackPanel.Margin.Right;
}


I just found that it does make a difference between by calling SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent directly after InitializeComponent() and by Loaded += SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent. For me I have a nested ListBox using ObservableCollection. Calling SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent after InitializeComponent() results in a very tiny size for that dynamic ListBox

Initialized event - too early, Loaded - too late. In between there is a SourceInitialized event. Try it. Use mine approach to measure container, rather than going yourself through its children.

So I don't know why it is doing this. But I assume you are right. But have you tried either solving it with a "ContentRendered" event? using the ContentRendered event ensures that the size adjustment happens after the content is fully rendered. This should reduce flickering, but if it still occurs, you might need to explore other options.
This might be a cheap shot but it would be the quickest way to my knowledge.
What you could also try is setting the initial Window to Hidden, perform your action and then loading it. This would resolve the issue with the resizing.
Both ways are dirty but could be effective
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        SetDialogWidthBasedOnContent();
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
   


" using the ContentRendered event ensures that the size adjustment happens after the content is fully rendered. This should reduce flickering, but if it still occurs, you might need to explore other options." - This is so wrong and so ChatGPTish ><

This is due to my poor english skills, I usually let ChatGPT run over the technical aspect of my answers to fix grammatical errors ensuring, the reader gets my point and not dying of a stroke in the attempt to understand what I try to tell

Related.

The content itself is not ChatGPT. The grammar of my post is corrected not the base content or the base statement itself. I write an answer in my mother tounge. Take the technical relevant part post it in there and let the GRAMMAR be altered not the overall context. I usually post it in and ask GPT to "translate to english please" thats all. I don't copy paste the question and let ChatGPT spit out an answer
